# uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rss, reader

First of all i'm new to android development,so i'm not very good in android....
I'm creating a rss reader and i'm using asyntask 
i created a java class named ReadRss but it's showing a weird error..
i'm using the latest version of android studio...

ReadRss.java

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
Context context;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String address = "https://rarbg.to/rssdd.php?categories=41";
URL url;
    public ReadRss(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading....");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
ProcessXml(Getdata());
        return null;
    }

    private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
if ( data !=null ){

    Log.d("root",data.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
}

    }

    public Document Getdata(){
        try {
            url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
            return xmlDoc;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

when i compiled it it show me a error like

**C:\Users\Shinto chakkiath\AndroidStudioProjects\rssexample\app\src\main\java\com\tecpiranha\rssexample\ReadRss.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.**

my logcat shows

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xa7fc1000: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
2019-06-02 01:26:08.035 20487-20504/com.tecpiranha.rssexample W/System.err: error:1000043e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INAPPROPRIATE_FALLBACK (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0xa7f85900:0x00000001)
2019-06-02 01:26:08.035 20487-20504/com.tecpiranha.rssexample W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
2019-06-02 01:26:08.035 20487-20504/com.tecpiranha.rssexample W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
2019-06-02 01:26:08.035 20487-20504/com.tecpiranha.rssexample W/System.err:     ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are an Indian like me and the RARGB is blocked in many countries including India, please refer https://waytohunt.org/rarbg-proxy/, to verify the issue turn on VPN in your testing device and have a try, it should work for some countries